# Array to string conversion error when working with a 2 multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Good morning

I seem to be catching an error in PHP,
 `
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\sample_page.php on line 80

I have an example multidimensional array as shown below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3791671
            [name] => photos
            [permissions] => Array
                (
                    [modify] => 1
                    [view] => 1
                    [collect] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3791677
            [name] => vehicle_incident_report_c_vehicle_details
            [permissions] => Array
                (
                    [modify] => 1
                    [view] => 1
                    [collect] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3791680
            [name] => vehicle_incident_report_c_vehicle_details_c_photos
            [permissions] => Array
                (
                    [modify] => 1
                    [view] => 1
                    [collect] => 1
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3791689
            [name] => inspection_photos
            [permissions] => Array
                (
                    [modify] => 1
                    [view] => 1
                    [collect] => 1
                )

        )
)
```

I am trying to format this array into a table format using the code below, but it gives me an array to string conversion error

```
// Transform data
$headers = [];
$rows = [];
$rowIdx = 0;
foreach ($array_example as $sample) {
   foreach ($sample as $key => $value) {
     if (!in_array($key, $headers)) {
         $headers[] = $key;
      }
     $rows[$rowIdx][$key] = $value;
     }
     $rowIdx++;
                    }

     // Display data
     $html = "<table style='width:100%' id='table_id'><thead><tr>";
         foreach ($headers as $header) {
             $html .= "<th>$header</th>";
         }
         $html .= "</tr></thead><tbody>";
         foreach ($rows as $row){
            $html .= "<tr>";
            foreach ($headers as $header) {
                $html .= "<td>";
                $html .= $row[$header]?? '';
                $html .= "</td>";
           }
           $html .= "</tr>";
          }
         $html .= "</tr></tbody></table>";
         echo $html;
```

Line 80 consists of

`$html .= $row[$header]?? '';`

Thank you in advance

`

Comment: and where is the line 80?

Comment: $html .= $row[$header]?? '';

Answer (score 1):

the error is not in PHP , it's in how do you access your array.

inherited loops does not mean that you will loop over the sub array by default

you are populate your array to be a multi-dimensional array like in this line

```
$rows[$rowIdx][$key] = $value;
```

While you are trying to access this array like a one dimensional array like this

```
$html .= $row[$header];
```

you need to access the two-dimensional array , looping over $headers array does not mean that you are looping over the `$row` array

so , this may fix your issue

```
foreach ($rows as $index => $row) {
    // ....
    foreach ($headers as $header) {
        //....
        $html .= $row[$index][$header] . '';
        //....
    }
    // ....
}
```